# How to set detect and install conditions in wix bundle hotfix chain so that the product can be uninstalled

Tags: wix

The setup is as follows: I have an RTM wix bundle (2.0) that has a 3 packages in the chain. We'll say P1, P2, and P3. Whether or not it matters P3 is an ExePackage and it is the one that is causing me trouble. Additionally, I am using a bootstrapper developed and maintained by my company so some things I can control and some I cannot.

In the RTM P3 package is defined as follows:

```
<PackageGroup Id="P3">
  <ExePackage Id="p3"
              Cache="yes"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="no"
              Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
              SourceFile="Resources\p3.exe"
              DetectCondition="P3Version"
              InstallCondition="Not P3Version"
              UninstallCommand="/quiet /uninstall /norestart">
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

All of that worked fine until I had to write a hotfix (patch) for the bundle. Specifically to patch P2. The first issue I ran into was when I would try to uninstall the hotfix. Uninstalling the hotfix only basically runs a reinstall on the RTM bundle and since P3 is installed it ends up being UNINSTALLED due to the conditions mentioned above.

As far as I know there is nothing I can do to modify the bundle conditions since it has already been shipped. If someone knows hot to patch a bundle that would be great.

Things I have tried:

Running a reinstall of P3 from a custom action only scheduled to run on MSIPATCHREMOVE. This did not seem to work because apparently multiple MSIs cannot execute simultaneously.

I added P3 to my hotfix bundle chain. This fixes the issue when uninstalling the hotfix only because the hotfix bundle now uninstalls P3 and then the reinstall of the RTM sees P3 does not exist...and installs it again. But this introduces a new problem. I have to be able to uninstall the entire product at one time from ARP menu. Executing an uninstall via the RTM uninstall menu is supposed to uninstall all related bundles as well. When this happens it seems that both bundles are trying to uninstall P3. The hotfix bundle seems to win and removes the exe from the package cache. This ends up causing an error in the RTM bundle and fails the uninstall.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below the horizontal rule is basically a description of why you are screwed but by re-reading your post I understand the issue a bit more so I'm giving a better fix to you issue.

First things first, don't use the InstallCondition here. I think you've stumbled into a worst case scenario using the InstallCondition. I think if you remove the InstallCondition from the Hotfix ExePackage description this will still work.

What you can do is modify the plan state of your P3 ExePackage in the Hotfix bootrapper application code only when you are uninstalling from the RTM bootstrapper.

(This is for the unmanaged c++ BA, should be applicable to the C# one just need to find the right methods/event handler)

So, in your Hotfix BA, we need to go to "OnPlanPackageBegin"

What we want to do here is plan to do NOTHING for the P3 ExePackage if the Hotfix BA is uninstalling and the relationType is not NONE. So something like this *I think*

```
virtual STDMETHODIMP_(int) OnPlanPackageBegin(
    __in_z LPCWSTR wzPackageId,
    __inout BOOTSTRAPPER_REQUEST_STATE *pRequestState
    )
{
    // stuff that was here already
    // ...

    if (wcsstr(wzPackageId, L"p3") && m_command.relationType != BOOTSTRAPPER_RELATION_NONE) // "p3" should be the Id of the P3 ExePackage 
    {
          pRequestState = BOOTSTRAPPER_REQUEST_STATE_NONE;
    }      

    return CheckCanceled() ? IDCANCEL : IDOK;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about the relationType but I believe this will plan to do nothing for the p3 ExePackage in the Hotfix BA when it is uninstalled/run by another bootstrapper application. This way if you uninstall the RTM the HotfixBA should leave the p3 ExePackage alone so it can get removed by the RTM BA.

I would test with doing modify/repairs of the RTM BA as well. You might need to add something like `&& m_command.action == BOOTSTRAPPER_ACTION_UNINSTALL` maybe to the if, I'm not sure.

I would also test upgrade scenarios because I'm not quite sure what will happen when it tries to remove the old RTM BA. I *think* it will use good reference counting and leave P3.exe behind but I'm not sure. If it does try to remove it when it shouldn't you might need author a new P3.exe which modifies the registry location (??) of the p3Version so that the old BA thinks it already isn't installed and just does nothing. If you can't change the the registry location you might need to modify the registry by scheduling p3 before your MSI install and deleting/moving the version registry and updating your detect condition appropriately. Lots to consider here...

---

The problem is your InstallCondition is ALWAYS false when the product is installed and therefore will always uninstall. InstallCondition does **not** behave as I initially expected it to and now I mostly avoid it.

[InstallCondition](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html)

> A condition to evaluate before installing the package. The package will only be installed if the condition evaluates to true. If the condition evaluates to false and the bundle is being installed, repaired, or modified, the package will be uninstalled.

You usually want to set this as a condition that MUST be met for your product to work properly. This can also be used as a property for a optional installation say some add-on that the user can choose to install or not during the UI phase of the bootstrapper.

Do not use it as a way to detect when to install because it's really a "Detect when it is possible to install and don't install/uninstall otherwise". The detect condition is what you use to determine when to install if the product is not present. Default value for InstallCondition is just always assume it should be installed.